# Issue converting Boolean to String (works some of the time but not all)

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, winforms, boolean

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong!

To explain the change in title, in testing this issue in a test project I found that it sometimes threw but not always (which I know makes it even harder to track down) in every case I am calling the Class the same way etc!

NOTE RE ANSWER - I have marked the answer below as correct as it does solve the problem even though no one has been able to explain why this issue is occurring!

The first examples below are simplified for ease of explanation, for the full code please scroll down.

I am reading from xml as follows:

```
Return XElement.Value
```

In this case `.Value` is either "True" or "False"

If I take the returned value (called ReturnedString for this Q) and do:

```
If ReturnedString Then
    'some code
End If
```

or

```
If CBool(ReturnedString) Then
    'some code
End If
```

It SOMETIMES throws an exception on the If statement `Conversion from string "False" to type 'Long' is not valid.`

**BUT**

If I do:

```
Dim ReturnBol as Boolean = ReturnedString
If ReturnedBol then
    'some code
End If
```

It is fine ALL the time!

It **ONLY** happens when reading from the xml.

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <_Weekly>
    <_Flag>True</_Flag>
  </_Weekly>
</Root>
```

I am sure i am missing something obvious - can anyone point me to it (please shout if I have missed any vital info!).

Thanks in advance.

Extract Code:

The read code is in a class as follows:

```
Public Class MyXml
    Dim __Weekly As New _Weekly
    Public Property Weekly As _Weekly
        Get 
            Return __Weekly
        End Get 
        Set(value As _Weekly) 
        End Set 
    End Property
    Public Class _Weekly
        Property Flag As String
            Get
                Return Readxml("_Weekly", "_Flag")
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                SaveToXml("_Weekly", "_Flag", value)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Private Shared Function Readxml(xmlItem As String, xmlname As String)
    Readxml = Nothing
    Dim CCXml As XDocument
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(XMLPath) Then
       CCXml = XDocument.Load(XMLPath)
       Dim xEl As XElement = (From El In CCXml.Root.Elements() Where El.Name = xmlItem).FirstOrDefault
       If Not IsNothing(xEl) Then
            Dim ChxEl As XElement = (From El2 In xEl.Elements() Where El2.Name = xmlname).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(ChxEl) Then
                Return ChxEl.Value
            End If
       End If
    End Function
End Class
```

So to return the string you do:

```
Dim myxml as New MyXml
If myxml.Weekly.Flag then

End If
```

Please do not give me a lecture on nesting classes and all the pitfalls, i am well aware of the potential issues but this happens to be what i need (suggestions or constructive criticism VERY welcome of course!)

Comment: This does not make any sense. Please, add a relevant portion of the code, such that we can replicate it and find the problem (which has to be somewhere else). Also, does it happen the same with DirectCast?

Comment: You could try with `Return String.Compare(XElement.value,"True")` ?

Comment: @varocarbas Not sure what else you want, i can put in the complete function that produces `ReturnString` but it will make the Q fairly clunky to read! if i direct cast the same happens!

Comment: Do whatever you want. But this behaviour cannot be replicated. If I write If CBool("True") Then everything works fine. Thus the problem is in your exact conditions, most likely in your code (not in CBool). If you want to get help, you should allow helpers to get the error you claim. But, as said, do whatever you want; I have spent enough time here.

Comment: I will add the extract code to the Q now in case it helps!

Comment: @varocarbas If you do have a few seconds spare i have added the complete extract code, i only thought it might not be needed because i thought i was missing something very obvious! - Thanks for your input so far!

Comment: Can you please (but just if it is not too much trouble) to include the whole input file which provoke the problem you are complaining about, such that I (or anyone else) is able to text your exact conditions?

Comment: Also how are you calling this class (nd well... if you could fix the compiling errors of the posted code this would be marvellous; but not really required... our goal is helping you in anything you need without complaining).

Comment: `If myxml.weekly.flag.ToString` doesn't work because the `if` is waiting for an expression resulting in true or false. But if `If CBool(myxml.weekly.flag.ToString) Then` works, what's the problem? Aren't you getting what you want?

Comment: @chiapa thanks for your answer, i will probably accept it but waiting to see if anyone else comes up with a good reason as `myxml.weeekly.flag then` actually works perfectly elsewhere!!

Comment: That's odd, maybe someone will come and explain that. Thanks @OSKM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CBool` is a function used to convert expressions to a Boolean datatype. Its parameter can't be a string (other than "true" or "false"), and that's why the exception is thrown.

Try

```
If CBool(ReturnedString = "True") Then
    'some code
End If
```

Or

```
If CBool(ReturnedString.ToString()) Then
        'some code
End If
```

Comment: Why does `If CBool("False") Then` not throw an  exception? You can DirectCast "True" to a Boolean but this doesn't work either with the returned string!

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception because "true" and "false" are exceptionally accepted strings. If possible, try `If CBool(ReturnedString.ToString()) Then)` - edited my answer

Comment: Exceptionally accepted strings? Can you please read the original post and understand the problem (also take a look at the CBool MSDN information)? The OP is not doing CBool("Anything")!, but CBool("True") a perfectly valid input of CBool or of DirectCast(, Boolean) or of the implicit cast occurring when doing Dim temp As Boolean = "True". Could you please, update your answer and correct so clear errors? "Its parameter can't be a string" -> where have you got such an idea from? Better wait until the OP updates his question, when the exact problem might be more clear.

Comment: Yes, try `CBool("zzz")` and you'll see that's not an accepted string - check if it accepts that. Anyway, I don't know why you're so angry, I'm just trying to help the man here. Even if my answer isn't correct or doesn't suit his needs, you could try to help me improving my answer or try to answer it yourself, maybe the objective of helping the one who is asking is achieved then.

Comment: Angry?! (I am one of the happiest persons I have ever met). Can you please re-read my comment and understand why CBool("zzz") does not meet what I am saying above? :) (-> to prove that I am happy)

Comment: `CBool(ReturnedString = "True")` is painfully redundant.... the `=` yields an expression anyways... and `if` can evaluate expressions...

Comment: Actually I just realized: `CBool(ReturnedString.ToString())` is even more painfull.... Why not use: `If CBool(ReturnedString = "True".ToString().ToString().ToString()) Then`

Comment: Is it "comedian day" today? Since I don't know what's in the `ReturnedString` and it's throwing exceptions, I thought maybe `ReturnedString` isn't equal to "true" or "false", maybe it's a different type or whatever. So, to avoid type mismatches (the asker refers `Conversion from string "False" to type 'Long' is not valid`) I thought that may be missing to him. Can't you stop being judges and try to just help askers and helpers alike?

Comment: Sorry for the sarcasm, i really got infected (as i'm inclined to it anyways) but just wanted to point out that you don't need to convert an expression to a boolean if its in an `if` clause and you sure as hell don't need to do the ToString() on a string... it's only there as string inherits object anyways.

Answer (score 0):

To get the according boolean value of a string like `True` or `False` you should use:

[Boolean.Parse(String value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your case:

```
If Boolean.Parse(ReturnedString) Then
 'some code
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated the question as when trying @Chiapa suggestion I found that it sometimes works fine but not always so i am really now trying to find out why not always!

Comment: I'm really curious as to what your ReturnString look likes in case of an exception. Did you happen to have look at it?

Comment: it looks like "False" or "True" Nothing more or less.

Comment: Then maybe there is a space or a control character in there? Look at it's bytes just before putting it into the parser

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as it is working in some instances but not in others I am fairly confident to say there is not - having said that I always try out suggestions so I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not positive if the value exists or can be parsed, consider using [Boolean.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) instead of Boolean.Parse.

Comment: Well i considered that to come without saying... the only problem is that in my opinion an invalid string shouldnt convert to `False` since it was **not** `False` but invalid...

Comment: Sorry I retract that :) I just remembered that TryParse yields the result in an out param. So no interference there. But it remains misleading in my view, since the success of the operation can be confused with the actual result quiet too easily.

Comment: It would be trivial to create a IsTrue shared method that wraps Boolean.TryParse and would remove the confusion if you think it is worth the effort.